# mongodb update structure of database, super slow

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

If I need to update the structure of `70,000` documents. Looping through the cursor and updating each one is super super slow. It does about 10/s

Any tips on how to update the document structure (essentially updating some values in every document in my database)

```py
import json
import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

for document in applications.find({}):
    document["name"] = {"name": document["name"], "level": "999"}
    applications.update_one({}, {"$set": document})
```

The database is hosted on a decent enough server, and I feel like its the code which is limiting the speed. Not the server.

https://gyazo.com/f8227e0cd24c3f5c9c0cb67e52e5a9ca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt is iterating the find() result set at js level and fire individual update back to database, which creates a lot of overhead and slow.

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can update with an aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: {
        name: "$name",
        level: "999"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sd279ta_CKj) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks you very much :)